# Mysterious line in perl

Tags: perl, variables

I am reviewing some perl code and ran across this line

```
$> = $<;
```

It's older code and I wish I could have been more descriptive in the title above (sorry folks). What does this line do?

Comment: It's an older code Sir.. But it checks out. I was just about to let them through.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It sets the [effective user id](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24EUID) to the [real user id](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24UID).

Comment: `$>` is the effective user ID; `$<` is the real user id.

Comment: So all actions will be done with privilege of user who executed the script

Comment: Awesome! I knew you guys could help me through... Nikki

Comment: @Ivan Yes. It's effectively ignoring the setuid bit for whatever follows.

Comment: @Nikki reading the excellent documentation bundled with Perl also helps.

Comment: @Sinan:  I haven't checked, but this has to be in the docs.  They are very good, and make up for some of the odd features in the language (like variables with names that are single, non-intuitive, punctuation marks).

Answer (score 11):

Spig is correct. There are a whole whack of other global variables whose name is only a symbol. You might find it useful to check [`perldoc perlvar`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) for a list of them and what they mean.